# Is a photon redshifted differently depending on whether it is passing inside a galaxy or in a cosmic void?

Tags: cosmology, redshift, gravitational-lensing

Consider two photons that are emitted in different directions from the same source in the Milky Way, a long time ago (redshift $z_i$.) One of the photons leaves the galaxy, travels for, say, 50 Mpc, and then passes really close to a black hole. The black hole deflects the photon by a 180° angle, so that the photon comes straight back towards the Milky Way and it is detected by one of our telescopes at $z=0$. Since the emission of the photon, the universe has been expanding, therefore the photon has been redshifted by an amount $z_i$.

The second photon instead never leaves the Milky Way. After being emitted it travels towards a black hole inside the galaxy and starts orbiting it, extremely close to the photon sphere. It does so for a long time, until it is finally ejected and goes straight towards one of our telescopes, hitting it about at the same time as the first photon.
This second photon has spent all its life inside the Milky Way, an overdense region of the universe where the Friedmann equations (that assume an homogeneous universe) are not valid.

Will the second photon be redshifted like the first one?

In other words, **I am asking if the cosmological redshift experienced by a photon depends only on the time (and place) of emission and absorption, or if it depends also on the path undertaken.**

Comment: Contrary to some of the commentary on the top "Related Question", it might depend, at least partly, on the path, for reasons described on p.6 of Davis & Lineweaver's "Expanding confusion", whose preprint can be found by its title on << Arxiv >>.